# Sleep Go until certain point in time independent of OS

Tags: go, time, operating-system, sleep

I know that you can use the `time.Sleep(d Duration)` function to let the Go program wait for a certain duration. Now I have the use-case that I want to keep the point in time even when the whole OS goes to sleep.

So as an example: When I sleep the go program at 1pm for two hours. And I turn off my computer on 2pm for half an hour until 2:30pm. I still want the code to resume at 3pm and not at 3:30pm. 
(Of course when I sleep my OS longer than 3pm the code should resume immediately).

How should I do that with go? Is there a nice function or library for that or should I use `cron` as a workaround?

Comment: You'd have to do a check time -> sleep loop until the time is the time you want it to go off.

Comment: Thanks, then Ill just do sth like that! I would have thought that the Best-Practice would be more complicated than that though

Comment: Note that with this approach you cannot distinguish between "I let the OS sleep for an hour", "I turned the local time forward one hour", or "I changed my local timezone one hour towards the east". It's probably fine since you considered cron as a workaround, but I wanted to mention it anyway.